# How do I select an Id from a SelectList using asp.net core 3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms, asp.net-core

I'm iterating through a list and populating a table with the last column having a edit button to edit that Id specific request.

Right now no matter what button i click it always takes me to the edit page of the first Id in the list, also the url has each Id listed in it like this.
/EditRequest?SelectedId=127&SelectedId=128
why is the SelectedId set to all values in the list? and how do I only pass the one Id of the one selected?

Here's my model

```
    public class MyRequestsViewModel
    {
        public MyRequestsViewModel()
        {
            this.MyRequests = new List<SelectListItem>();
        }
        public List<SelectListItem> MyRequests;
        public int SelectedId { get; set; }
    }
```

I'm iterating through MyRequests and want to send SelectedId to the controller

```
    <form method="get" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="EditRequest">
    <table id="SortRequestsTable" class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>SortID</th>
                <th>SortCriteria</th>
                <th>Edit</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model.MyRequests)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@item.Value</td>
                    <td>@item.Text</td>
                    <td>
                        <input asp-for="SelectedId" type="hidden"  value="@item.Value" />
                        <button>@item.Value<span class="sap-icon">&#xe038;</span></button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

And my controller keeps saying that SelectedId is 0

```
public IActionResult EditRequest(MyRequestsViewModel requests)
```

I got it working with this. But I don't want to display the Id value in the button.

```
<input asp-for="SelectedId" type="submit" value="@item.Value" /><span class="sap-icon icon-16">&#xe038;</span>
```

I've also tried using asp-route-SelectedId tag helper but I'm not entirely sure how to implement that.

Comment: In general, you should not pass `MyRequestsViewModel` to `EditRequest` , you should only pass `SelectedId` and then query the related data from database for security concern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try code below to achieve Edit from Index Page.

```
<a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.ID">Edit</a> |
```

And Controller for accept request

```
// GET: Tickets/Edit/5
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    var ticket = await _context.Tickets.FindAsync(id);
    if (ticket == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }            
    return View(ticket);
}
```

Comment: This seems to be the correct way to implement asp-rout-id. This worked for me